# arm-none-eabi-as error for STM320f on mac

Tags: terminal, arm, stm32, cortex-m, newlib

In terminal, I try to convert assembly code to object code

```
arm-none-eabi-as -o sample.s sample.o
```

Assembler messages:

> Error: can't open main.o for reading: No such file or directory

And deletes sample.s at that directory I was operating in.

Answer (score 2):

-o defines the output file name you need to do

```
arm-none-eabi-as -o sample.o sample.s
```